# Calculating descriptives on matching groups

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm working with a pandas DataFrame having the following structure:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'brand' : ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 
                   'value' : [111, 111, 222, 222, 333, 333, 444, 444, 444, 555, 555, 555, 666, 777, 888]})

print(df)

   brand  value
0      A    111
1      B    111
2      A    222
3      B    222
4      A    333
5      B    333
6      A    444
7      B    444
8      C    444
9      A    555
10     B    555
11     C    555
12     A    666
13     B    777
14     C    888
```

I would like to calculate somes descriptives on the above table:

First, count the number of groups having different brands that match to the same value. Here's a helping visual:

[image]

As you can see, there are 5 groups where brands inside each group are different that match to the same value. So basically, I want to write a query that would output the number of those groups (5 in this case).

---

Second, I would like to have a more detailed view of each group. Specifically, calculate the:

- Number of groups with a single records : 3 (the last 3 records)
- Number of groups with 2 records : 3 (groups red, green and blue)
- Number of groups with 3 records : 2 (groups purple and black)

I tried to come up with a solution on my with without any success using groupby statements. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you simply looking for `df.groupby("value").count()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**first problem**

Use [GroupBy.size](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) 
and add the values ​​True result of the comparison with 1:

```
(df.groupby('value').size()>1).sum()
```

Output:

```
5
```

**second problem**

you could create a dataframe like this using [Series.value_counts](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
df_count=df.groupby('value').size().value_counts().reset_index(name='Nº Groups').rename(columns={'index':'Nº Records/Group'})
print(df_count)
```

---

```
   Nº Records/Group   Nº Groups
0                 2           3
1                 1           3
2                 3           2
```